# react js, как сохранить измененный стейт

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hook

Всем привет. Друзья, вопрос  про хуков...  когда меняем начальный стейт , но в том же компоненте после работы другого хука, первый хук возвращает начальный стейт.... как лучше избегать этого? с помощью useEffect или вывести первый хук в контейнерный компнент, то есть на верхний уровень, где второй хук не обновит его? прошу еще теоретическое обьяснение этой ситуации? Вот данный ког работат нормально, но когда я нажимаю кнопку выполнив другой хук, у меня начальный стейт этого кода обновляеться...как быть?

const [count, setCount] = useState(1000);
    const [points, sumPoints] = useState(0);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setCount(count => count - 100), 1000);
    answers.map(answer => {
        if(answer.clicked){
            clearInterval(interval);
            if (answer.status){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    sumPoints(points => points + count)
                }, 2000)
            }
        }
        return answer;
    });
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [answers, count, sumPoints]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд следует отталкиваться от стейта;
Есть стейт который при изменении вызывает хуки;
Всё что нужно, так это расписать правильный порядок изменения значений в стейте (на конкретном примере) и затем запрограммировать реакцию на эти изменения.

P.S. Хуки вызываются в той последовательности (один за другим) в которой они описаны;
Чтобы вызвать инициализацию стейта из хука, надо указать пустой массив в зависимостях (это означает что хук сработает всего один раз на componrntDidMount)

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Инициализируем стейт, и в этот хук больше никогда не возвращаемся
}, []);
```